# Get the correspondent values based on variables names stored in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, tibble

In one tibble I have values that are variable names in another tibble.
I need to list the values in a specific row in the second tibble of the column names contained in each row of the first tibble in a fast way. How can I do it?

My data has the form:

```
# Observations in is tibble says which variables of the tibble_b occurred at each case:
tibble_a <- tribble(
        ~a, ~b, ~c,
         4,  2,  5,
         4,  3,  1,
         2,  5,  5
        )
# This tibble contains values for the variables at different times:
tibble_b <- tribble(
        ~`1`, ~`2`, ~`3`, ~`4`, ~`5`,
         100,  112,   98,  107,   85,
          71,   76,   97,   80,   15,
           2,   61,   54,   37,   42
         )
```

I need to create a tibble that contain the values in `tibble_b` for the numbers in the first one, for, let's say, the first row, for all the rows in `tibble_a`. That is, basically, to obtain this tabular data:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 107 | 112 | 85 |
| 107 | 98 | 100 |
| 112 | 85 | 85 |

My problem is, `tibble_a` has hundreds of thousands of rows, and, of course, both has more columns. Since I have to perform tests and comparisons on multiple samples of row indexes of `tibble_b`, using something like below is very time consuming.

```
for(current_row in 1:nrow(tibble_a)) { 
  for(current_col in 1:3) {
   tibble_of_results[[current_row, current_col]] <- tibble_b[[1, tibble_a[[current_row, current_col]]]] 
  }
}
```

Can someone suggest any efficient way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

tibble_a |>
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x) unlist(tibble_b[1, x], use.names = F)))
#       a     b     c
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   107   112    85
# 2   107    98   100
# 3   112    85    85
```

You can use the values of the column to column index `tibble_b`. For example, for `tibble_a[[1]]`:

```r
tibble_b[1, c(4, 4, 2)]
#     `4`   `4`   `2`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1   107   107   112
```

We then simply convert that into a vector using `unlist`. Then we can apply this approach across all columns using `across(everything(), ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is functional programming approach using `purrr` package:

```
fetch_values <- function(row) {
  map_dbl(tibble_a[row, ], ~tibble_b[[1, .x]])
}

map_dfr(seq_len(nrow(tibble_a)), fetch_values)

 A tibble: 3 × 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   107   112    85
2   107    98   100
3   112    85    85
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tibble_a %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("id") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, values_to = "var") %>% 
  right_join(., 
             {tibble_b[1,] %>% pivot_longer(everything(), 
                                names_transform = as.numeric, 
                                names_to = "var")})  %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = -var)

#> Joining with `by = join_by(var)`
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   id        a     b     c
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1       107   112    85
#> 2 2       107    98   100
#> 3 3       112    85    85
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

If it's just about the first row of `tibble_b` (not sure) we can do

```
quickdf = \(l) {
  class(l) = "data.frame"
  attr(l, "row.names") = .set_row_names(length(l[[1L]]))
  l
}
tibble_a = quickdf(tibble_a) # tibble_a = as.data.frame(tibble_a) 
tibble_a[] = as.numeric(tibble_b[1L, ]
                 [match(unlist(tibble_a, use.names = FALSE), colnames(tibble_b))])
```

giving

```r
> tibble_a
    a   b   c
1 107 112  85
2 107  98 100
3 112  85  85
```

Read more about `quickdf()` [Chapter 24.4.2](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-improve.html#as.data.frame).

Comment: Is it from plyr? And it is experimental, right? Your link is not working for me btw.

Comment: @M-- Excuse me. Repaired the broken link. Not too sure about the history and where it's exported from nowadays. Will look it up.

Comment: Apparently, plyr is a little old and it's [retired](https://github.com/hadley/plyr?tab=readme-ov-file#status-) but somewhat mantained to keep it on CRAN. I knew the existance of the package, but regarded it as old and superseded until now. Seems to have very interesting [functions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.9).